# Why are the assumptions for Baire's theorem important?

Tags: general-topology

I've seen the proof for Baire's theorem (countable union of closed boundary sets is a boundary set, or equivalently, countable intersection of open dense sets is a dense set). I wouldn't repeat it nonetheless.

Still, could you help me understand why are the assumptions for this theorem important, i.e. why does the space have to be metrizable and complete? (Besides that without it the proof doesn't work)? I noted that boundary sets indeed have to be closed, as otherwise $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ would have empty interior.

But why completeness (/metrizability)?

Comment: "Boundary set" is not standard terminology in English.  I think you mean "with empty interior"

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The condition is not "metrizable and complete", but "completely metrizable": completeness is a property that can't be defined on a topological space without some additional structure (such as a metric) that let's you define the notion of a Cauchy sequence..

Comment: To elaborate on @RobArthan's point, note that a given space can be metrized both completely and incompletely: the metric spaces $(0, 1)$ (incomplete) and $\mathbb{R}$ (complete) are topologically identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see why e.g. metrizability is not enough, consider $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual topology. $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets (the singletons).

Answer (score 2):

Topological spaces in which countable intersections of dense open sets are dense are called [Baire spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space).  Besides complete metric spaces, these include locally compact Hausdorff spaces.